# Clicking on anchor links only works sometimes

Tags: html, css, href, anchor

I have added drop down menus to my website, but am running into a problem where my links do not always work when clicked. Sometimes clicking a link just makes the drop down menu disappear, but if you keep trying eventually it will take you to where you are trying to go.

I originally suspected it had something to do with the transition duration, but playing around with the transitions/waiting for the transitions to complete before clicking does not appear to change anything.

Here is the html block for the drop down menu navbar

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: -20px;
}

.dropdown {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.Python,
.cPP {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.Python ul,
.cPP ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: disc;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(86, 114, 117);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.Python li,
.cPP li {
  background-color: rgb(216, 192, 147);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}

.Python li:hover,
.cPP li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(207, 151, 46);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.Python a,
.cPP a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.home a {
  font-size: 1.0em;
  align-items: center;
}

.home a:hover {
  color: rgb(24, 218, 208);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.dropdown button {
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: turquoise;
}

.dropdown button:hover {
  color: rgb(132, 255, 243);
  border-color: rgb(255, 145, 0);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.Python button:focus+ul,
.cPP button:focus+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="home">
      <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Python">
      <button>Python</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../1DKinematics/1DKinematics.html">&nbsp;1-D Kinematics</a></li>
        <li><a href="./pendulumFriction.html">&nbsp;Damped Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./drivenPendulum.html">&nbsp;Driven Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./elasticPendulum.html">&nbsp;Elastic Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./doublePendulum.html">&nbsp;Double Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./elasticDoublePendulum.html">&nbsp;Elastic Double Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./RKvsEC.html">&nbsp;Runge-Kutta vs. Euler-Cromer </a></li>
        <li><a href="../oceanography/bobInWater.html">&nbsp;Dynamics of Body in the Ocean </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cPP">
      <button>C++</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The hover state on the list items makes it look like you're clicking on the link when in fact you're just clicking on the list item. Style the anchor elements to completely cover the list item.

Comment: You mean to do <a hfref="../foo.html"><li>FooPage</li></a>? I found that this did not fix the issue.

Comment: No, that's invalid HTML. Change the CSS so that the anchor element covers the list item.

Comment: Perfect, that seems to have fixed the issue. The cause of the problem makes a lot of sense, smart job picking up on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things you might want to do to fix the problem.

1. Style your `a` tag so it takes full width/height (easier to click)
2. Change `pointer-events: all` to `pointer-events: auto`, since `all` is only for SVG (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

```js
// For test only
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown a').forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('clicked')
  })
})
```

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: -20px;
}

.dropdown {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.Python,
.cPP {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.Python ul,
.cPP ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: disc;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(86, 114, 117);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.Python li,
.cPP li {
  background-color: rgb(216, 192, 147);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}

.Python li:hover,
.cPP li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(207, 151, 46);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.Python a,
.cPP a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.home a {
  font-size: 1.0em;
  align-items: center;
}

.home a:hover {
  color: rgb(24, 218, 208);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.dropdown button {
  background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border-color: turquoise;
}

.dropdown button:hover {
  color: rgb(132, 255, 243);
  border-color: rgb(255, 145, 0);
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.Python button:focus+ul,
.cPP button:focus+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

/* Code added */
.dropdown ul li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="home">
      <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="Python">
      <button>Python</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../1DKinematics/1DKinematics.html">&nbsp;1-D Kinematics</a></li>
        <li><a href="./pendulumFriction.html">&nbsp;Damped Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./drivenPendulum.html">&nbsp;Driven Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./elasticPendulum.html">&nbsp;Elastic Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./doublePendulum.html">&nbsp;Double Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./elasticDoublePendulum.html">&nbsp;Elastic Double Pendulum</a></li>
        <li><a href="./RKvsEC.html">&nbsp;Runge-Kutta vs. Euler-Cromer </a></li>
        <li><a href="../oceanography/bobInWater.html">&nbsp;Dynamics of Body in the Ocean </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cPP">
      <button>C++</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This does not explain why the links sometimes work.

Comment: @Sean Thanks ! After a long time editing the answer, I noticed you guys figured it out. Just gonna leave it here for someone else in the future.

Comment: @LSE, thanks for this! It is nice to know how to make the entire width/height of the box clickable. Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Sean's suggestion, the fix was to ensure the anchor is not covered by the list, that way we click the links in the anchor instead of the list element. Here is the fix in CSS:

```
a{
z-index: 100;
}
```